# My auth app does not save data to session

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, express-session, passport-local-mongoose

Creating Auth application using express mongoose and passport js.
after adding mail verification using nodemailer server sptoped adding  user from req.user to res.locals.currentUser can be seen from middleware. before adding email verification it was functioning correctly.

```
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session(sessionObject));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.locals);
  res.render("index");
});
app.get("/login", (req, res) => res.render("login"));
app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureFlash: true,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    req.flash("success", "Welcome Back!");
    res.redirect("/");
    console.log(req.user);
  }
);
```

[image: source code]

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ 
Heiko Theißen check it now

Comment: If you want the user to kept in the session, you must write it to `req.session.currentUser`, not to `res.locals.currentUser`.

Comment: than i cannot access currentUser from views. or i can?

Comment: You can write it to both. But `res.locals` will expire at the end of the current request.

Comment: and what about req.user its only for single request too? conside that i am using passport.js

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen it doesnt works check my comment to your answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem was: I was working in a local environment and had set the session cookie to `secure`.

Since Localhost runs on HTTP and not HTTPS, the browser was not sending the session cookie to the Application after the App redirected, which prevented Passport from loading the session data and creating the `req.user` key.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `req` and `res` expires at the end of the request, only `req.session` is written to the session store (`sessionObject`) and from there carried over to the next request.

If you want to keep the current user in the session, write it to `req.session.currentUser`. Then you need `passport.js` and `req.user` only during the first request, where the session is established.

Comment: doesnt helped in passport documetation is said that when used passport middlewares like app.use(passport.session()); it automaticly adds user to session and user can be accessed throw req.user but its undefined as i tried to add usser to session manualy in my login and register routes.